# How to access the app.config value in the class library?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application which is using a dll of a class library. I am unable to access the `app.config` value in the class library

How I'm trying to access `app.config`:

```
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conStr"].ToString();
```

this is returning a null value

Also when I try to use `ConfigurationManager` it says not found or missing assembly reference.

using System.Configuration is also added .

Comment: .NET class libraries don't use their "own" config file - they look in the config file of the application that uses them.

Comment: The comment above me should be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must put the `AppSettings` value inside the `web.config` of the application, because it override the `app.config` from the class library.

Add a reference to `System.Configuration` namespace in the class library project, them get the value you're expecting from the `web.config` file, not from the `app.config` file.

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to the `System.Configuration` library in your project, then get your key like this

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conStr"]
```

Notice that a web application will search for a `web.config` file and not an `app.config`!

Comment: For a web app, you should use the `WebConfigurationManager` (instead of the "plain" `ConfigurationManager`)

Answer (score 0):

AMembers's answer should work and get you running. But I like to *tell* ("tell; don't ask") my library where they should be connecting. Instead of having your library locate it's connection string, let the calling code supply it:

```
var myLib = new MyLib(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conStr"]);
```

This way, whether your configuration is in a web.config/app.config/custom config/registry/.ini-file, your library doesn't care.

Comment: And for a web app, use `WebConfigurationManager` (instead of the "plain" `ConfigurationManager`)

Comment: good point. let's consider my code example coming from a Console Application.